# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property playerNo of # which has only a getter on line 4

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm moving from using the hacky JavaScript classes of old (functions and prototypes) to the new ES6 classes.

I'm probably doing something stupid but I'm not sure why I'm not allowed to do this:

```
class Player{
    constructor(playerNo){
        this.playerNo = playerNo;
    }    
    get playerNo(){
        return this.playerNo;
    }

    set cards(playersCards){
        this.cards = playersCards;
    }
    get cards(){
        return this.cards;
    }
}

var steve = new Player(1);
```

It gives me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property playerNo of # which has only a getter on line 4`

So, I tried the below:

```
class Player{
    constructor(playerNo){
        this.playerNo = playerNo;
    }   
    set playerNo(no){
        this.playerNo = no;
    }
    get playerNo(){
        return this.playerNo;
    }

    set cards(playersCards){
        this.cards = playersCards;
    }
    get cards(){
        return this.cards;
    }
}

var steve = new Player(1);
```

Which gives me: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on line 6` (which is the line `this.playerNo = no;`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using getters/setters here at all? You don't need them.

Comment: They're good practice, right? Also, I plan to implement validation soon, and without setters that would involve changing code in a lot of places. What reasons are there not to use them?

Comment: No, they are not good practice when they don't do anything special (and additionally, they're rather slow). They just complicate the code. Yes, you can use them *when* you implement validation, that's fine, but you shouldn't use them until *then*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have recursion with setting `playerNo`.

In the `playerNo` setter, try setting `this._playerNo = 0`.

In the rest of the code, continue to make a distinction between the name of the setter method and the internal property that stores the data.

Comment: Knew it would be something silly. Thanks. I guess the constructor may as well be `constructor(playerNo){
        this._playerNo = playerNo;
    }`? Or is it worth calling the setter from the constructor?

Comment: I would have the constructor design set the property directly. Slightly more direct and does not expose the internal property to the public.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a getter as means of "protected" property, one you can only read from the outside and it has no setter ...

However, in your code you were trying to call a non-existing setter `this.playerNo = playerNo` and within your getter you were recursively referring to the same getter `return this.playerNo` instead of using the hidden `this._playerNo` property within it (same in your constructor) - hence the stack overflow error.

Remember that with getters/setters you need some extra storage for your value, such as the private `_playerNo` property (unless you're delegating the storage elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You might wonder, but there are use-cases where "**re-defining a getter**" as "**property with *fix* value**" is intended:

> E.g. Instantiate a *heavy object* **on-demand**

1. Once a getter is accessed, we re-define it as property and value.
2. Next access just returns the value from property (like a cache...)

```js
let a = 10;
let b = 10;
class Player {
  get clubHistory() {
    return Object.defineProperty(this, 'clubHistory', {
      value: `clubHistory ➜ ${++b}`
    }).clubHistory;
  }

  static get team() {                            // … first ivoce Player.team …
    return Object.defineProperty(this, 'team', { // … re-defines static getter 'team' as property …
      value: `team ➜ ${--a}`                    // … e.g. new Team(..)
    }).team;                                     // … return new value (only relevant for first call)
  }
}

let player1 = new Player();
console.log('player1', player1.clubHistory); // 11 from get
console.log('player1', player1.clubHistory); // 11 from prop

let player2 = new Player();
console.log('player2', player2.clubHistory); // 12 from get
console.log('player2', player2.clubHistory); // 12 from prop

console.log(Player.team); // 9 from static get
console.log(Player.team); // 9 from static prop

console.log('player1', player1.constructor.team); // 9 from static prop
console.log('player2', player2.constructor.team); // 9 from static prop
```